# React setState does not update a state array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I am trying to change the `state` in a class component by using `setState`.

More specific I have a table, and I want to edit/update one of its elements. For this case, I am passing the indeces to the `handleTableFieldOnChange` function for the position of the value in the array.

Since I know that I should not mutate the state, I used an external library to deep copy the tables array/list.

The deep copy and the new value assignment works. The deep copy worked also with the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tables));` alternative.

**Problem:** For some reason the `this.setState(...)` does not change the tables value.

I do know the `setState` is asynchronous, this is why I used the callback and within it, the `console.log(...)` to check the updated value.

`console.log(...)` still emits the old value.

```
private handleTableFieldOnChange(val: boolean | string | number | [number, string], tblRowIndex: number, tblIndex: number, tblColINdex: number) {
        const cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
        const newTables = cloneDeep(this.state.tables);
        if (newTables && newTables[tblIndex] && newTables[tblIndex].items ) {
            newTables[tblIndex].items![tblRowIndex][tblColINdex].value = val;
        }
        this.setState( {tables: newTables}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.tables)
        })
    }



state: State = {
  tables: [],
  report: this.props.report,
};

constructor(props: DetailProp, state: State) {
  super(props, state);                                
  this.initFieldsAndTabels();
}

 private initFieldsAndTabels() {
        if (this.state.report && this.state.report.extraction_items) {
            this.state.tables = [];
            this.state.report.extraction_items.forEach((extractionItems) => {
                    this.state.tables.push(extractionItems);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `handleTableFieldOnChange` looks fine to me.

However in `initFieldsAndTabels` you are applying `push` on state directly instead of calling `setState` which may probably cause the issues:

```js
this.state.report.extraction_items.forEach((extractionItems) => {
  this.state.tables.push(extractionItems); //#HERE
});
```

Also as [React.Component docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) state you should not call `setState` in `constructor` (you are calling `initFieldsAndTabels` in `constructor`. Instead you could use `componentDidMount`.

P.S. If you want to add those extraction items in the constructor then you need something like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // method should return a new array/object, but not modify state
    const tables = this.initFieldsAndTabels();
    this.state = {
      tables,
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did I get something wrong? In the constructor, I am not using `setState` but directly `this.state` as also stated in the documentation link you provided. I am just using the function `initFieldsAndTabels ` for this case. Why would this be a problem?

Comment: Well, I put it a bit ahead. 
I was saying that you are applying `push` to state which is wrong `this.state.tables.push`.
So if you are to replace that part with `setState` which is more safe and predictable, it will be still called in `constructor` which is undesirable.

Comment: Ah, right. Shouldn't I still initialize the state within the constructor? This is how I see it done in the docs. Why should I implement this in the `componentDidMount` instead?

Comment: You can initialize it in `constructor`, but don't run operations on it right there.

Comment: Is the `this.state.report.extraction_items.forEach((extractionItems) => {
                    this.state.tables.push(extractionItems);
            });` considered to be an operation?

Comment: Since you are trying to do `push` on state - yes.

Comment: Updated the answer, please see P.S.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229691/discussion-between-alex-buznik-and-georgios).